# Some Views not being hidden when fragment changes

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have been following the [tutorial for fragments from Google](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

I tried adding a button to the news_articles.xml layout. The problem is that this button does not disappear like `ListView`, when the article_view.xml is called. When I run the app, it displays the `ListView` along with the test button. After clicking on one of the news headlines, the description of this news is displayed along with the button.

What do I need to modify, so that the button (or any other element) will not be shown? This sample image shows the button which remains seen after clicking a news item.

[image]

Code for news_articles.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Code for article_view.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/article"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
        implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);

        // Check whether the activity is using the layout version with
        // the fragment_container FrameLayout. If so, we must add the first fragment
        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

            // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
            // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
            // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            // Create an instance of ExampleFragment
            HeadlinesFragment firstFragment = new HeadlinesFragment();

            // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an Intent,
            // pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
            firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

            // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
        }
    }

    public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
        // The user selected the headline of an article from the HeadlinesFragment

        // Capture the article fragment from the activity layout
        ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);

        if (articleFrag != null) {
            // If article frag is available, we're in two-pane layout...

            // Call a method in the ArticleFragment to update its content
            articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);

        } else {
            // If the frag is not available, we're in the one-pane layout and must swap frags...

            // Create fragment and give it an argument for the selected article
            ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
            newFragment.setArguments(args);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

HeadLines code:

```
public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {
    OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

    // The container Activity must implement this interface so the frag can deliver messages
    public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
        /** Called by HeadlinesFragment when a list item is selected */
        public void onArticleSelected(int position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // We need to use a different list item layout for devices older than Honeycomb
        int layout = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;

        ListView listViewTest=(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayList<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        your_array_list.add("Test1");
        your_array_list.add("Test2");
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =      
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, your_array_list);

        setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        // Create an array adapter for the list view, using the Ipsum headlines array
        //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout, Ipsum.Headlines));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // When in two-pane layout, set the listview to highlight the selected list item
        // (We do this during onStart because at the point the listview is available.)
        if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment) != null) {
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception.
        try {
            mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Notify the parent activity of selected item
        mCallback.onArticleSelected(position);

        // Set the item as checked to be highlighted when in two-pane layout
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
    }
}
```

ArticleFragment code:

```
public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {
    final static String ARG_POSITION = "position";
    int mCurrentPosition = -1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // If activity recreated (such as from screen rotate), restore
        // the previous article selection set by onSaveInstanceState().
        // This is primarily necessary when in the two-pane layout.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_POSITION);
        }

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // During startup, check if there are arguments passed to the fragment.
        // onStart is a good place to do this because the layout has already been
        // applied to the fragment at this point so we can safely call the method
        // below that sets the article text.
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            // Set article based on argument passed in
            updateArticleView(args.getInt(ARG_POSITION));
        } else if (mCurrentPosition != -1) {
            // Set article based on saved instance state defined during onCreateView
            updateArticleView(mCurrentPosition);
        }
    }

    public void updateArticleView(int position) {
        TextView article = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.article);
        article.setText(Ipsum.Articles[position]);
        mCurrentPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // Save the current article selection in case we need to recreate the fragment
        outState.putInt(ARG_POSITION, mCurrentPosition);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using fragments?

Comment: I have added the code, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new xml file that will be used in MainActivity - for example activity_main.xml

   ```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       tools:context=".MainActivity">
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. In MainActivity modify the code, so that it uses the new xml layout -

   ```
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   ```
3. Further modify the onCreateMethod so it looks like this

   ```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
       return;
    }

    HeadlinesFragment firstFragment = new HeadlinesFragment();
    firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
   }
   ```
4. In HeadLinesFragment override the onCreateView method

   ```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup)   inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_articles, container, false);      
       return rootView;
   }
   ```

That should be all. Try it out by adding some sample buttons in the news_articles.xml.